# cin for an int inputing a char causes Loop that is supposed to check input to go wild

Tags: c++, char, int, buffer, cin

This is a function of my game it will ask for input and cin into "iAuswahl"!
Then the while loop is checks if it is one of the Values i want 1-9 if not it activates and is supposed to ask for new input. Witch it does for int.
But if i input a char like r it will go crazy and just keep giving me back my cout and skip the cin!
My questions are why does it do it and how do i stop it?

```
void zug(string sSpieler, int iDran){
    int iAuswahl;
    char cXO = 'O';

    if (iDran == 1)
    {
        cXO = 'X';
    }

    cout << sSpieler << ", Sie sind am Zug. Bitte waehlen sie eins der Felder.\n" << endl;
    grafik();
    cout << "Sie sind >> " << cXO << " <<." << endl;
    cin >> iAuswahl;
    cout << endl;

    while ( 
        iAuswahl != 1 
        && iAuswahl != 2 
        && iAuswahl != 3 
        && iAuswahl != 4 
        && iAuswahl != 5 
        && iAuswahl != 6 
        && iAuswahl != 7
        && iAuswahl != 8 
        && iAuswahl != 9
    )
    {
        cout << "Kein gültiges Feld bitte wählen sie noch einmal!\n" << endl;
        cin >> iAuswahl;
    }
    feldfuellen(iAuswahl, cXO);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When an error occurs when reading from a stream, an error flag gets set and no more reading is possible until you clear the error flags. That's why you get an infinite loop.

```
cin.clear(); // clears the error flags
// this line discards all the input waiting in the stream
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Also, it's wrong to use the results of input operation if you don't know whether the read succeeded in the first place. You can't make assumptions about the value of `iAuswahl`. That's one of most often made errors by newbies using streams. Always check if the input operation was ok. This is most easily done by using `operator>>` in boolean context:

```
if (cin >> some_obj) {
    // evaluates to true if it succeeded
} else {
    // something went wrong
}
```

And, my oh my, this line

```
while (iAuswahl != 1 && iAuswahl != 2 && iAuswahl != 3 && iAuswahl != 4 && iAuswahl != 5 && iAuswahl != 6 && iAuswahl != 7 && iAuswahl != 8 && iAuswahl != 9)
```

can be just this:

```
while (iAuswahl < 1 || iAuswahl > 9)
```

A correct loop could look something like this:

```
while (true)
{
    if ((cin >> iAuswahl) && (iAuswahl >= 1) && (iAuswahl <= 9)) break;
    std::cout << "error, try again\n";
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

Comment: Works fine with cin.ignore() and cin.clear() but i get a run throug the loop for each character entered...
guessing i need so me clauses for ignore but i'am new to this so how do i resolve this
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n')
into a code that works for me.

Comment: @JensKrüger You need to include `<limits>`, sorry I forgot to mention that. `cin.ignore()` ignores only a character at a time.

Comment: Thanks again but i can't seem to get it right.... i want the limits to be the leght of the input right?
How do i do that? If i put it too long it ignors the next inputs too if its to short i get multiple runs through the loop!

Comment: @JensKrüger Do you intend to type several numbers at once? Like `2 4 7`?

Comment: No only one nummber at a time but if someone type ins something like
    "I hate this game"
it will cause problems if i have the limits set wrong!

Answer (score 3):

You need to clear error flag after reading wrong type, otherwise `cin` will refuse to read anything, as it will be in the invalid state. Also, you need to ignore that character that was not read by `cin`, because it will stuck you into a forever loop because it will always try to read from that character.

```
while (iAuswahl != 1 && iAuswahl != 2 && iAuswahl != 3 && iAuswahl != 4 && iAuswahl != 5 && iAuswahl != 6 && iAuswahl != 7 && iAuswahl != 8 && iAuswahl != 9)
{
    cout << "Kein gültiges Feld bitte wählen sie noch einmal!\n" << endl;
    cin.clear();
    // #include <limits>
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    cin >> iAuswahl;
}
```

Also,

```
while (iAuswahl != 1 && iAuswahl != 2 && iAuswahl != 3 && iAuswahl != 4 && iAuswahl != 5 && iAuswahl != 6 && iAuswahl != 7 && iAuswahl != 8 && iAuswahl != 9)
```

can be written as

```
if(iAuswahl < 1 || iAushwahl > 9)
```

Don't forget to initialize `iAushwahl` to `0`, or to some other value, because if your `cin >> iAushwahl` fails, you will read the uninitialized variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using your iAuswahl variable to do any sort of math, which you aren't in this function, just make the variable a char variable, there is no reason in making a variable an int if it is not doing anything that would require it to be an int.