# C++ Checking if input is a int and redo the input until it is a int

Tags: c++, char, int

I'm currently doing a simple "how old are you" calculator. But i want to check if the user entered a int or a char. So i made this:

```
 if (!cin) {

cout << "Error" << endl; 
cin >> year;

}
```

But if i do this and enter a char it just goes through and doesn't allow a new input.

Comment: It still has the flag set and the bad input sitting there.

Comment: There is no loop, why would you expect it to go again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference: [cin for an int inputing a char causes Loop that is supposed to check input to go wild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18400620/cin-for-an-int-inputing-a-char-causes-loop-that-is-supposed-to-check-input-to-go?rq=1)

This is a duplicate but the canonical answer is to do:

```
std::cin.clear(); // clears the error flags
// this line discards all the input waiting in the stream
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Then do something like:

```
int year;

 while (!(std::cin >> year)) {
    std::cin.clear(); // clears the error flags
    // this line discards all the input waiting in the stream
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
 }

// do something with year
```

So if your input looked like:

```
a
b
c
42
```

It will print error three times.

Comment: Thanks, i'm giving this a try tomorow!