# while( cin >> value ) breaks the loop when i entered a character

Tags: c++, c++11

In the past, I have been programming in c# but now I am learning c++. Why the while loop exit in c++ when I enter a string and in c# if I don't use tryparse it will give an exception. Does the c++ explicitly do something like tryparse in the backend ?
Sorry if my question 
I am using codeblocks as my c++ IDE.

I am reading the book c++ primes and code a simple program that continuously takes integer as input until a string is entered. I wrote the same code in c# but it leads me to an error. So I have to use tryparse method in C#.

```
int value = 0;
```

In C++

```
while( cin >> value );
```

In C#

```
while( value  == int.parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28623658/cin-integer-and-while-loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why the while loop exit in c++ when I enter a string

`operator>>` performs error handling internally. If it fails to extract an integer, the stream enters a failure state, and the loop is checking the stream's state, so it exits when the stream fails.

> in c# if I don't use tryparse it will give an exception.

Yes, because that is the way [`int.parse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse) is defined to work.

You can get similar behavior in C++ by [enabling exceptions in the stream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions) . That way, if an extraction failure occurs, a [`std::ios_base::failure`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/failure) exception is thrown.

> Does the c++ explicitly do something like tryparse in the backend ?

In a way, yes.

> I am reading the book c++ primes and code a simple program that continuously takes integer as input until a string is entered. I wrote the same code in c# but it leads me to an error.

Your C++ and C# codes are not equivalent.

Your C# code reads an entire line as-is, discarding the line break, and then tries to convert the entire line as-is to an int.

Your C++ code discards leading whitespace - including line breaks - until it encounters a non-whitespace character, then it tries to read an int value, and whatever follows after it - including a line break - remains in the stream for subsequent reads.

> So I have to use tryparse method in C#.

If you don't want a failed conversion to throw an exception, then yes.

Comment: @Caleth I added that

Answer (score 0):

C++ knows to parse for an integer because you defined the variable "value" as type int.

From the C++ reference:

> As an object of class istream, characters can be retrieved either as
>   formatted data using the extraction operator (operator>>) or as
>   unformatted data, using member functions such as read.

Comment: I know I can also achieve the same behavior with tryparse but what I want to know how c++ knows that it is not a integer and without throwing an exception he is handling the character.

Comment: @RivenCallahan Pardon, I read the question the other way around. C++ knows to parse for an integer because you defined the variable "value" as type int.

Comment: means C++ can handle these format exceptions in C# without any type of explicit code ?

Comment: @RivenCallahan Yes, the stream extraction operation has exception handling, see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/